# Strange behaviour of symlink /var

Tags: terminal, path, symlink

I have a pretty new MacBook and got this from our central IT department pre-installed.
I experienced a problem, which I first thought was related to Terraform, but after investigation this seems to be a general problem at all.

Having a look at simple `cat` commands:

```
ls -al /var/tf-test/                                                                 
total 8
drwxrwxrwx   3 root     wheel   96  3 Aug 11:00 .
drwxr-xr-x  30 root     wheel  960  3 Aug 10:57 ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 user     wheel  198  3 Aug 11:00 backend.hcl

cat /var/tf-test/backend.hcl                                                         
I am fine

pwd                                                                                  
/Users/user/tf-test

cat ../../../var/tf-test/backend.hcl                                                 
cat: ../../../var/tf-test/backend.hcl: No such file or directory
```

This is pretty strange ....since `cat` should resolve the symlink und should automatically point to the real path, right?

This basically leads to my Terraform to not deploy anything, since Terraform is generating a relative path from the current directory to a backend-config (a parameter) and then couldn't resolve it:

```
pwd                                                                                  
/Users/user/tf-test

terraform init -backend-config /var/tf-test/backend.hcl                          
Initializing the backend...
Error: Failed to read file
The file "../../../var/tf-test/backend.hcl" could not be read.
```

Permissions seems to be ok, isn't it?

```
ls -la /
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel    192 28 Mai 01:32 private
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  admin     11 13 Jul 13:05 tmp -> private/tmp
lrwxr-xr-x@   1 root  admin     11 13 Jul 13:05 var -> private/var
```

Guys, this freaks me out.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Nothing seems amiss here. Why not use /private/var for the install and not have it get confused with symbolic links? (Or better, put terraform in /usr/local which is the best place for this?) If you’re just looking for general advice - I can answer that, but this question seems stuck as XY - you have a specific error with a specific installer and rather than posting that, you’re asking about something else “teach me X” so you can go solve “Y” perhaps?

Comment: Terraform is called by various scripts and backend-configs are generated automatically ... they were put to /var/folders/... and cant be read afterwards. I don't know what is the missing piece why this wouldn't work. solving the 'cat' issue should solve everything else. but this is completely irrational behaviour. this symlinc should defenitly work :(

Comment: I'll answer how I would attack this - hopefully someone has a better answer. Also know you can put too many `../../..` safely but not enough clearly can fail.

Comment: Also isn't that a bug in terraform. If you give an absolute path it should use an absolute path report the bug. As you have found links mess up relative paths using several..

Comment: cat(1) doesn't resolve the symlink.  The shell does.  Only if it doesn't expand does cat(1) see the unexpanded line.  Symlinks can't cross filesystem mounts.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start with two things.

1. `sudo -s`
2. Judicious use of `file` hopefully can help pick apart the error in thinking, permissions or execution here.

File should report correct results all the way back to root, and then all the way back to `/private/var` - once you’ve got a string of good results - repeat the sequence of `file` checks to test `../../var/whatever`

```
# file ../../var/                                      
../../var/: directory
# file ../../var/com.twocanoes.tcscryptotoken.tcstoken/        
../../var/com.twocanoes.tcscryptotoken.tcstoken/: directory
# file ../../var/com.twocanoes.tcscryptotoken.tcstoken/token.sh 
../../var/com.twocanoes.tcscryptotoken.tcstoken/token.sh: POSIX shell script text executable, ASCII text
```

If you are on Catalina - realize you are crossing filesystem boundaries and firmlinks are in play as well as sym links. You can tell that with a `df` command and if it shows you have a Data APFS volume in addition to the system volume. Hopefully you don’t need to wait for terraform to fix deployment - it might be a simple error, but this is why we’re moving everything into `/usr/local` so that we get user and non-system installation off the read only disk of macOS sooner rather than later.

```
# diskutil list|grep Macintosh
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     122.0 GB   disk1s1
   5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.2 GB    disk1s5
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Investigating.... but strange is, that as long as I'm root, it works and file will print the correct results. but as user, it won't work (https://pastebin.com/dwr3WQfy) phew

Comment: I suspected permissions @Smoki